# Use Converted Column Letter In VBA Range

Tags: excel, vba

I have been able to find the column number and convert it to the letter, but I cannot figure out how to use the converted letter in defining a range. I keep getting a run time 1004 error.

I am trying to identify a column which contains the largest value in a specific row. Then use that column  to find the first non zero cell and insert a row. Below is my code:

```
  Sub ColNBR_Insert()
 Dim maxCol As Long
 Dim rngMaxCell As Range, rngVals As Range, C As Range, Where As Range
 Dim lastNum0 As String
 Dim ColLtr As String

 Set rngVals = Worksheets("Charts").Range("F3:M3")

 With Application.WorksheetFunction

 Set rngMaxCell = rngVals.Find(.max(rngVals), LookIn:=xlValues)

 If Not rngMaxCell Is Nothing Then
 maxCol = rngMaxCell.Column

' MsgBox "The max value is in column " & maxCol
 End If

 End With

 Set rngVals = Nothing
 Set rngMaxCell = Nothing

'Convert To Column Letter
ColLtr = Split(Cells(1, maxCol).Address, "$")(1)

'Display Result
'MsgBox "Column " & maxCol & " = Column " & ColLtr

lastNum0 = "<>0"
Set C = Range(Range(ColLtr), Range(ColLtr))

C.Find(What:=lastNum0, After:=C(1), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Select
Selection.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown

End Sub
```

Comment: Just use `Cells` and you don't have to convert at all.

Comment: @BigBen beat me to it. No need to convert.

Comment: Or `Columns`...

Answer (score 0):

No need to do all this conversion... just use `Columns`.

```
Set C = Range(Range(ColLtr), Range(ColLtr))
```

although problematic, is probably easier done with

```
Set C = Columns(maxCol)
```

Comment: So just set the range to Columns(maxCol)? (Set C = Columns(maxCol))

Comment: So when I set C to the Columns(maxCol) I get a type mismatch error in the C.Find(What:=lastNum0, After:=C(1), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Select statement. Any ideas on how to fix this so that a blank row will be inserted?

Comment: `After:=C.Cells(1)`. Then you need to test if the `Find` succeeded instead of immediately `Select`ing (which you don't actually need to do anyway).

Comment: Well, I have tried your suggestion and nothing is working. Can you tell me how to use the column to find the first value <> 0? I can do it if I know the column, but I am trying to identify the column dynamically as it is always changing.

Comment: `"<>0"` is just text. You could maybe use a filter instead.

Comment: Okay, can you help me out? I've been playing with for 3 days and my mind is mush. I am just trying to use the column I've identified and use that identified in a subsequent statement to find the last non-zero number.

Comment: This code works to find the last non-zero + insert row, but I specified the column "I". I need to be able to change the column dynamically..

Dim i As Long
i = Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Do Until Range("I" & i) <> 0
i = i - 1
Loop
'MsgBox Cells(i, 1).Address
Cells(i, 1).Select
Selection.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown

Comment: Can you edit your question with the revised code you're using, instead of posting in a comment?

Comment: Will do...do I ask a new question?

Comment: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60955446/edit) your original question, or ask a new one if you prefer that.

Comment: Just posted it as new.